# Sobreescribir evento de un control

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He creado un formulario base el cual tiene un control, entonces los formularios que hereden de este formulario base deben sobreescribir el evento `Click` de este control.

Evento de un control del Formulario Base:

```
public partial class CustomFormBase : Office2007Form
{
    public CustomFormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bubbleBar1_ButtonClick(object sender, DevComponents.DotNetBar.ClickEventArgs e)
    {
        BubbleButton button = sender as BubbleButton;

        switch (button.Name)
        {
            case "bubbleButtonNuevo":
                MessageBox.Show("Nuevo");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonEditar":
                MessageBox.Show("Editar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonGuardar":
                MessageBox.Show("Guardar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonBuscar":
                MessageBox.Show("Buscar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonEliminar":
                MessageBox.Show("Eliminar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonSalir":
                MessageBox.Show("Salir");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces el formulario que hereda de esta base tiene que sobreescribir el evento, para poder crear ***Nuevo, Editar, Guardar, Buscar, Eliminar, Salir***.

En esta imagen muestro un formulario que hereda de `CustomFormBase`.

[image: Hereda de formulario base]

Necesito sobreescribir en el formulario que hereda de `CustomFormBase` el evento que esta en el, el cual muestro lineas arriba.

```
public partial class Form1 : CustomFormBase
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Deso sobreescribir evento de control bubbleBar1_ButtonClick
}
```

Comment: Para poder sobreescribir un método, este debe estar definido como `virtual`o `abstract`. Mira [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ebca9ah3.aspx)

Comment: Analiza bien la operativa del proyecto que estes haciendo, porque igual te interesa crearte una Interface que luego implemente cada formulario en funcion de tus necesidades.
Quizas este link te pueda interesar:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa288461(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder sobreescribir el método, necesitas definir un método `virtual` y que no sea `private`, para que las clases hijas que hereden de tu clase de base tengan acceso.

En este caso, tal vez lo más fácil es crear un nuevo método con esas características en tu clase de base, y que el método existente `bubbleBar1_ButtonClick` le delegue el trabajo:

```
public partial class CustomFormBase : Office2007Form
{
    public CustomFormBase()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void bubbleBar1_ButtonClick(object sender, DevComponents.DotNetBar.ClickEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ManejaButtonClick(sender as BubbleButton);
    }

    protected virtual void ManejaButtonClick(BubbleButton button)
    {
        switch (button.Name)
        {
            case "bubbleButtonNuevo":
                MessageBox.Show("Nuevo");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonEditar":
                MessageBox.Show("Editar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonGuardar":
                MessageBox.Show("Guardar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonBuscar":
                MessageBox.Show("Buscar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonEliminar":
                MessageBox.Show("Eliminar");
                break;
            case "bubbleButtonSalir":
                MessageBox.Show("Salir");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Ahora sí puedes sobre escribir el nuevo método `ManejaButtonClick` en las clases hijas:

```
public partial class Form1 : CustomFormBase
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void ManejaButtonClick(BubbleButton button)
    {
        // ... lo que tu quieras.
    }
}
```